# QGIS3 vertex tool only works for points

Tags: qgis-3

I’m trying to use the vertex tool in QGIS3 on a Mac to edit a shape file someone else sent me. I can edit points without any problems, but when I try to edit lines or polygons the tool doesn’t work. When I move the mouse close to or into a polygon, the vertices and line segments don’t get highlighted as they are apparently supposed to.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

When the vertex editing tool is enabled, moving the mouse on a polygon feature should highlight its vertices.

Then you can make a right click on the polygon of interest, and only the vertices of this polygon will be highlighted. If you move the mouse over another polygon, its features will not be highlighted.

You can then right click again on another feature to see its vertices.

To get back to the original state, which highlights vertices of polygons by moving the mouse, you would do a right click on an empty area of the map. Let's note that the list of vertices is turned into a message telling us to right click on a feature.

Comment: The highlighting you describe is what I see for point features, but not for line and polygon features...